# Java FileOutputStream Windows/Linux

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, fileoutputstream

Hy I got this Code:

```
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("res/" + new java.util.Date().toString() +".properties");
```

I'm working on my Code at university (Laptop - Ubunutu) and at home (Desktop - windows).
I Sync the Eclipse Project with github and EGit.

Now I wasn't able to excecute this line of code on my Windows machine, but it's still working on my laptop.. the exact same Code..

Getting the Error:
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: res\Thu Jan 08 15:54:39 CET 2015.properties (Die Syntax für den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datenträgerbezeichnung ist falsch)`

And: `at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Sourc
     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)`

Comment: I believe you must prefix the spaces in the filename with a backslash on unix systems.

Comment: Please don't beg for upvotes, that's not how SO works ([reference](http://www.reddit.com/r/stackoverflow/comments/2rsftm/upvote_please_so_i_can_paticipate_more_in_this/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that `:` is not a valid character for a path name in Windows.

From the MSDN article "[Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)":

> [...]
>
> Use any character in the current code page for a name, including
>   Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set
>   (128–255), except for the following:
>
> - The following reserved characters:
>
>   - < (less than)
>   - > (greater than)
>   - : (colon)
>   - " (double quote)
>   - / (forward slash)
>   - \ (backslash)
>   - | (vertical bar or pipe)
>   - ? (question mark)
>   - * (asterisk)
>
> [...]

Answer (score 3):

Windows does not allow colons ':' in filenames.

Answer (score 2):

`new java.util.Date().toString()` will give date in following format

```
Thu Jan 08 20:51:01 IST 2015
```

It contains **:**
That character is not allow to use in names in windows. But you can use them in linux

Therefore if you want to use same thing in both platform, you have to change the format of the date may be using `SimpleDateFormat` or something else
e.g.

```
SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("YY-MM-DD");
System.out.println(sd.format(new Date()));
```